# output.grad None even after loss.backward()

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm confused...

My model output:
`tensor([[0.0000,0.1537],...],grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)`

If I use `print(output.grad)` it gives me `None` but even after gradient computation with
`loss.backward()` I get the same result, which again is `None`...

Even with
`with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):`
added, still the same.

I've tried now with multiple model variants, always the same.

I was achieving good result with my model there seemed no problem, now I see this and I'm not sure any more if there not might be a major flaw I didn't recognized so far.
But my model is learning, it improves so I guess it has to?

Why do I get None instead of an actual value?

Comment: Is output a leaf node? From its name it sounds like it probably isn't. Gradients are only retained for leaf nodes. Leaf nodes are tensors that have requires_grad = True **and were not a result of some previous computation**. I.e. they are leaves in the computation graph constructed by autograd. Most of the time the only leaf nodes are the parameters/weights of your model.

Comment: Posting a minimal example with code and showing what you expect and what you get would be a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting `None` because the gradient is only stored on the `.grad` property for leaf tensors. Those are tensors that don't have parents in the computational graph.

You can check whether a tensor is a leaf or not with [`is_leaf`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.is_floating_point):

```
>>> x = torch.FloatTensor([1,2,3])
>>> x.requires_grad = True
>>> x.sum().backward() # backward pass

>>> x.is_leaf
True
>>> x.grad
tensor([1., 1., 1.])
```

The tensor you printed shows `grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>` indicating it's the result of a ReLU layer, and therefore not a leaf tensor.

Here is an example of a non-leaf tensor:

```
>>> x = torch.FloatTensor([1,2,3])
>>> x.requires_grad=True
>>> z = x.sum()
>>> z.backward()

>>> z.is_leaf
False
>>> z.grad
None
```

Notice that `z` will show as `tensor(6., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)`.

---

Actually accessing `.grad` will give a warning:

> UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead.

And if you want to access the gradient on non-leaf tensors, following the warning message:

```
>>> z.retain_grad()
>>> z = x.sum()
>>> z.retain_grad()
>>> z.backward()

>>> z.is_leaf
False
>>> z.grad
tensor(1.)
```